# easy php error with mysql connection

Tags: mysql, easyphp, devserver

I've installed EasyPHP dev server 16.1, on windows 8, and I get PhpMyAdmin 4.5.3.1 returning "#2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."
So, please, which parameter is wrong here and where ?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to C:wamp\bin\mysql\mysql[your-version]\data
2. Copay and save "ib_logfile0" and "ib_logfile1" anywhere else.
3. delete "ib_logfile0" and ib_logfile1

This worked for me, i hope it works for you too.

Comment: Thanks, but I see no difference.